# Twitter (X) API returns "Your Tweet text is too long" for Blue Account

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am using twitter api java client lib to post a tweet larger than 250 chars (only 2600 or so), to a Twitter (X) blue account. I get a 400 error with message 'Your Tweet text is too long'. I am able to post the same long tweet through the web interface. Are there different limits between the api and web interface?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer by posting in a Twitter Developer support forum. The API only supports 280 max characters per tweet.